# Как получить значение со стороннего сайта на хостинге

Tags: php, wordpress

Когда я пытаюсь получить код страницы другого сайта с помощью php функции file_get_contents, я ничего не получаю. Как я понял это хостинг блокирует. Как я могу получить атрибут poster тега видео со страницы отдельного видео tik tok средствами php. Например: https://www.tiktok.com/@dina/video/6726851336517766406?langCountry=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на то, что сервер определяет UserAgent

```
 $ curl https://www.tiktok.com/@dina/video/6726851336517766406\?langCountry\=ru
{"statusCode":200,"contentType":"application/json","content":""}%
```

С выставленым агентом - уже другое:

```
$ curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" https://www.tiktok.com/@dina/video/6726851336517766406\?langCountry\=ru        
Redirecting to <a href="https://m.tiktok.com/v/6726851336517766406.html?langCountry=ru">https://m.tiktok.com/v/6726851336517766406.html?langCountry=ru</a>.%
```

Добавляем редирект...

```
 curl -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" https://www.tiktok.com/@dina/video/6726851336517766406\?langCountry\=ru 
<!doctype html><html>
        <head>
        <script>

    window._I18N_LANG_ = 'ru';
...
<video id="tiktokVideo" class="video" ...
...
</body><script></script></html>%
```

Вам нужно запрашивать контент с выставлением юзерагента. Например используя [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

Comment: С вашим юзер агентом: Redirecting to m.tiktok.com/v/6727681442584825093.html Я использовал другой юзер агент и смог вывести код страницы который был мне нужен. Вот код php:
 
`$userAgent = "Opera: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";
 
$url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@deepins/video/6727681442584825093"; 
$ch = curl_init( $url );
 
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent ); $html = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); echo($html);`

Comment: Ну я взял первый попавшийся под руку юзерагент :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - использовать `curl`.

```
<?php

// Create a URL handle.
$ch = curl_init();

// Tell curl what URL we want.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, http://localhost:4000);

// We want to return the web page from curl_exec, not 
// print it.
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

// Set this if you don't want the content header.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Download the HTML from the URL.
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// Check to see if there were errors.
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    // We have an error. Show the error message.
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
else {
    // No error. Save the page content.
    $file = 'content.html';

    // Open a file for writing.
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w');

    if(!$fh) {
        // Couldn't create the file.
        echo "Unable to create $file";
    }
    else {
        // Write the retrieved
        // html to the file.
        fwrite($fh, $content);

        // Display a message to say
        // we've saved the file OK.
        echo "Saved $file";

        // Close the file.
        fclose($fh);
    }
}

// Close the curl handle.
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Подробнее в источнике: [PHP Get URL: Download HTML Pages or Get the Page URL in PHP](https://caveofprogramming.com/php-tutorial/php-get-url-download-html-pages-or-get-the-page-url-in-php.html)